# Bitcoind JSON-RPC - PHP user handling

Tags: bitcoind, php

I asked this question on bitcoin forum too (just for the record):
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=430972.new#new

I am trying to develop a php web application (a game, and not a gambling site) where users can make in-game purchases. Now if I am understanding it right, The architecture (using bitcoind and Json-rpc api) should be:

- When a new user registers - generate a new address for the new user:

  > $bitcoin->getnewaddress("username");

  Store that wallet address for later use in my DB.

  Display that address and let a user send bitcoins to that address.

  Check the balance of that address using the

  > $bitcoin->getbalance($username,0)

  for unonfirmed balance  and

  > getbalance($username,6)

  confirmed balance.

  Now I can let the user buy my in-game items
  and use

  > $bitcoin->move($useraddress, $myaddress, $amount)

  to debit his account and give him the stuff he needs.

Questions:

```
1. Does this sound about right?  Or am I completely off here! 
2. How long does it take for the unconfirmed balance to show up?  [$bitcoin->getbalance($username,0)] 
3. $bitcoin->move($useraddress, $myaddress, $amount)  is a change of bitcoins between addresses within my wallet, so this should be
offchain and instantaneous, right? 
4.  How can some gambling dice sites like coinroll.it ( https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=191176.0) accept unconfirmed
transactions and lets  people play instantly? are they just taking
the risk or there is something that I am not aware of. 
5. How can I test out my bitcoind/php application with testnet? Anyone has any experience of this?
6. Suggestions on Security are welcome...
```

I am going to make parts of my code open source when I figure this shit out

Answer (score 1):

You are very correct, but:

1. I would use getaccountaddress instead of getnewaddress. If the user doesn't exist, which is the case for a new user, the wallet will create a new one anyway.
2. I always would use the user's name to recover from the wallet his address, there's no sense to store it again on a DB. ¿?

The time for a balance to be confirmed depends on the coin and its network.

$bitcoin->move($useraddress, $myaddress, $amount) Yes, it is instantaneous. There's no transaction broadcasted to the net.

How can I test out my bitcoind/php application with testnet? Anyone has any experience of this? ---> Go to the wiki, U have to set a specific parameter on bicoin.conf

Answer (score 1):

**Do not** use bitcoind's accounts feature. Handle user/address associations in your DB instead.

Even Gavin Andresen himself has said:

> ... the bitcoind "accounts" code hasn't been optimized for that.  For
>   example, computing an account's balance loops through all transactions
>   in the wallet, so will take an increasing amount of time the more
>   transactions you have in the wallet.

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=40430.0

As for how to handle transactions/purchases in your game, I'd recommend setting up a field in your users table to store a user's balance. When a user deposits to their personal deposit address you'd update the field with their new balance. Set up a cron task that runs every minute and calls a script that does something like this:

1. Pull latest 10000 transactions from bitcoind and store them in an array.
2. Filter out transactions with less than 2 confirmations, or whatever number makes you feel comfortable.
3. Insert all confirmed transactions into a DB table called "transactions." Don't allow duplicates. Add a boolean field called "processed"
4. When you're ready to process transactions to the users' accounts, pull all rows where processed = 0 and category = 'receive'. Process each deposit by adding the value of the transaction to the user's account, and set processed = 1 on the processed transactions.

When a user buys something in-game, just subtract the purchase amount from their balance.

This will be a lot more efficient, scalable, and easy-to-use than relying on bitcoind for user balance-keeping. It will also be a lot easier to migrate data around in the future, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct on most of it rest can be experienced in development process. So I suggest you to start development and ask if you find it difficult to fix issues.

Comment: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin gives you either the command line option or the configuration file option to use testnet.